# How to insert Hyperlink in answer

Tags: discussion

I am new here, while answering other people's questions, I can't insert any hyperlink.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at your answer window.

[image]

Can you spot the hyperlink button?

[image]

Click on it. The following window appears.

[image]

In the field marked with red arrow you add your website address.

[image]

[image]

Click on AddLink

[image]

Enter description

[image]

Note that your description is also shown under Answers window with an underline.

That underline denotes that the hyperlink has been created.

[image]

If the link is clicked, the targeted web page opens.

Shortcut -

Press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

to directly open the Insert Hyperlink window.

Answer (score 4):

All of this information and more is included in the formatting guide in the help center. You can find it [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 3):

You can also include links in comments, like this:
[image: Welcome-comment]

To insert hyperlinks like that in comments, you write

```
[text to display](link to website)
```

Important: there must be **no space** between ] and (.

The example above was written like this:

```
Welcome to Pets! Please take a minute to take the 
[tour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tour) and have a look at the 
[help center](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help).
```

To take it one step further, there are shortcuts for certain links like 
    [help]
    [tour]
    [ask]
    [answer]

A complete list can be found [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

That shortens the above example to:

```
Welcome to Pets! Please take a minute to take the  
[tour] and have a look at the [help].
```

Comment: Hi Elmy! Thanks for this assistance, and for linking to the list of comment shortcuts. I learned how to use it while on another site, and have found it to be a great benefit! It works on all SE sites, and it's not only easy, but it doesn't count against the number of characters in the comment, as the other methods do.